# eureka heartbeat distribute load

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

We have two eureka instances running and are replicated, however I would like to know if it is possible to configure clients to send heart beats to both servers (alternating).

We want to be able to run eureka on small vm's and add more when neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to put a load balancer between your services and Eureka Peers.

Comment: hum, was trying to use DNS to round robin between the instance as introducing a load balancer means more hops and more points of failure :/